# Poll a filp for read, blocking with timeout (kernel module)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm writing a linux kernel module that needs to read some data from a serial device.

I'm using filp_open() to open the device and then kernel_read() to read from there.

How can I poll the filp (returned by filp_open) to know if there is data available for read?

I know I could open it in NONBLOCKING mode and then keep polling it, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to put my thread to sleep and be waken up when data becomes available.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that kernel core doesn't provide mechanism for in-kernel polling (or `select`-ing) files. The [poll_table_struct structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.18/source/include/linux/poll.h#L43) is open-ended, so implementing simple polling of a single file shouldn't be a complex task. Note, that needs for polling a file in the kernel space is .. unusual. Kernel usually doesn't do such things.

Comment: dev files are provided for user space which can't get to devices directly.  The kernel is likely already getting an interrupt when data is available